Eglot/clangd fails to find compilation database
When trying to connect to clangd through eglot, I failed to find a lot of symbols. When inspecting the eglot/clangd communication with eglot-events-buffer I saw the following error message:
[stderr] I[10:48:58.787] Failed to find compilation database for /home/dov/hello-qt/mainwindow.cpp

However, the compilation database was created through cmake and resides in:
/home/dov/hello-qt/build_debug/compile_commands.json

Since it was not found automatically, I tried to add it explicitly in /home/dov/hello-qt/.clangd:
CompileFlags:
     CompilationDatabase: /home/dov/hello-qt/build_debug/compile_commands.json


However, I still get the above error.
What's missing?
My version of clang is clang version 18.1.8 (Fedora 18.1.8-1.fc40).
My version of eglot is Version: 1.12.29 (part of emacs-29)

This seems to be a question about clangd, rather than Emacs. I suggest consulting the clangd documentation.

Thanks. Now I understand. clang only looks for the compilation_commands.json file in the project directory. Since it is residing in a subdirectory, I must either use an environment variable CLANGD_FLAGS or make a symbolic link from the compilation directory to the project directory.
